# Where should I prefer and avoid cartridge bearings in a bicycle?

Tags: bottom-bracket, hub, headset, bearings

All bicycle bearings, hubs, bottom bracket and headsets used to be cup and cone
bearings. However, recently there has been a trend to replace these with
cartridge bearings in new parts.

Is this a good path?

What benefits and drawbacks do cartridge bearings have? Where should they be
preferred and where should they be avoided in a bicycle?

Answer (score 5):

I'll keep this answer short and simple.

Cartridge bearings from reputable manufacturers such as NTN, NSK and FAG will outlast their loose ball bearing counterparts assuming no maintenance is done.

90% of the issue arises when people do not use cartridge bearings from reputable manufacturers. As such, the argument that cartridge bearings are "unreliable" compared to their loose ball counterparts arises.

Comment: Bear also in mind that there are many counterfeit bearings on end consumer markets. It is difficult to find reliable distributors who sell small batches to consumers. Nonetheless, is worth the effort as quality differs greatly.

Comment: @gschenk Most of the time, avoiding counterfeit bearings involves the phrase "If the price is to good to be true, it probably is".

Comment: There's a big assumption right after "assuming"

Comment: @Lien028 yes and no. Unusually low price is a strong indicator of counterfeit bearings. However, counterfeit dealers learned that too and just charge more. What is more, the big brands on consumer markets are often sold with revenue margins that allow room for legitimate 'sales' pricing. (Compare SKF and NKE bearing prices, production costs and quality are, supposedly, roughly equal.) For our purposes the main consequens: source from reliable sellers only; Strongly doubt stories on the net about horribly bad  bearings from quality brands.

Comment: Of course, your advice applies to everything we purchase online @gschenk . That is why you should source your bearings from well-reviewed sellers. I get mine from Hambini.

Answer (score -3):

First, let's take a look at different types of cartridge bearings. There are
angular contact bearings that require an axial preload and can handle both
radial and axial loads, and deep groove radial bearings that are best at
handling radial loads but can handle usually axial loads as well. Headsets use
angular contact bearings, whereas hubs and bottom brackets have to use deep
groove radial bearings.

The angular contact bearings are nearly always full complement (are fully
filled with balls) because it is easy to snap together their races. However,
deep groove radial bearings are hard to make full complement. The reason is
that the parts have an overlap and thus easy filling is made by half-filling
them with balls (half complement) in one side, putting the center race in,
redistributing the balls evenly, and adding a retainer to prevent the balls
from ever going to the same side in use. This method is known as offset filling
and was invented by [Robert Conrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_bearing#Conrad).
There are slot filled full complement bearings too but they are poor at
handling axial loads and thus won't last long in a bicycle hub for example.

**Bottom brackets: cartridge bearings are acceptable**

Historically, bottom brackets had a square taper spindle with cup and cone
bearings. The too-small axle was prone to failures but the
[eleven 1/4" balls on both sides](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-BB-7400_7600-0729.pdf)
were big and numerous enough. However, a drawback of cup and cone bearings
as used in bottom brackets is that the bearings are "backward" unlike
what they are in a hub for example, so the design increases bearing loads
([details](http://pardo.net/bike/pic/fail-008/000.html)).

Then to simplify changing the entire assembly, square taper cartridge bottom
brackets proliferated. They share the too-small axle of the cup and cone square
taper bottom brackets, but despite the "cartridge" name at least the Shimano
offerings still use cup and cone bearings
([source:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lar7mIMmTRE) twelve
7/32" bearings on one side and eighteen 5/32" bearings on another side).

To solve spindle failures, Octalink was offered with bigger spindle.
Unfortunately, the faulty design lacking press fit leads to left crank
arm loosening and the big spindle leaves little space for bearings.
Apparently Shimano uses cup and cone bearings with eighteen 1/8" balls
on both sides ([source](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-BB-7700-1657B.pdf)).

Finally a solution was found to bottom bracket problems with Hollowtech
II that moves bearings outboard so that both the bearings and the
spindle can be big. It is an implementation detail that Hollowtech II
uses cartridge bearings but the bearings are large (37x25x7 mm,
[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fT0cRpDzhqk)) so
even being half complement is not a disaster, and the most of the cost
of a Hollowtech II bottom bracket is the bearings so changing the
entire threaded parts is not a problem.

Thus, because the only satisfactory bottom bracket is Hollowtech II, because
all cup and cone bottom brackets have the bearings "backward" increasing their
loads, and because Hollowtech II can use big bearings, it is not a problem to
use industrial cartridge bearings instead of cup-and-cone bearings in bottom
brackets, except perhaps in press fit frames where bottom bracket swap requires
expensive tools (such frames are best ignored as they are a disservice to
cyclists).

**Headset: cartridge preferable**

Early bicycle headsets used cup and cone bearings and they failed with a
failure mode called "indexed steering" where the steering develops a notch in
the straight position so that it takes a bit of force to turn the steering away
from this position. Later, the cause was found to be
[vibrations the bearings can't absorb](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/brandt/indexed-steering.html),
and by adding a conical or spherical interface at both contact points of the
bearing solved the issue. This naturally leads to using angular contact
full complement cartridge bearings. Because the bearings are angular contact,
they can be very easily made full complement so the bearings don't suffer
from the typical problem of cartridge bearings that only half complement is
possible.

When compared to for example cartridge bearing hubs where changing bearings
requires an expensive tool, these angular contact bearings are very simple to
change. In fact simpler than changing cup and cone bearings where the cups
required a press fit tool to change.

Because cartridge bearings solved a genuine problem in early cup and cone
headsets, and because cartridge bearings are simpler to change than cup and
cone bearings, in the headset application, cartridge bearings are preferable.

**Hubs: cartridge should be avoided**

Traditionally, hubs used 3/16" cup and cone bearings in the front and 1/4" cup
and cone bearings in the rear. However, recently, a problem in the quick
release system was found by the adoption of disc brakes: the front quick
release skewer self-loosens gradually on disc brake bicycles, eventually
causing the front fork to jump out of the front wheel during hard braking. As
this is dangerous, manufacturers switched from quick release system to thru
axles on disc brake bicycles. Unfortunately, the desire to use 11-tooth
sprockets in the rear hub mandates a maximum diameter for the bearings, and the
thru axle made the hub axle larger, so not much space is left for the bearings
and thus 5/32" balls are used in today's thru axle cup and cone hubs. Only time
will tell whether they are durable.

A cartridge bearing hub has the same restrictions that a cup and cone hub has in
that the bearings must fit into a confined space, but has many additional
drawbacks: no bearing service is possible without an expensive bearing press,
and the bearing has reduced lifetime due to needing to use the same size balls
that a cup and cone bearing would use
(due to needing to fit to the same confined space), but with no possibility of
having a full complement of balls and needing to have half complement due to
the offset filling used to manufacture the cartridge bearings. Typical
cartridge bearings used in hubs are 28x15x7 mm which is arguably too small
especially as a half complement bearing when compared to e.g. the 37x25x7 mm
used in bottom brackets. The 28mm outside diameter cannot be made larger due to
fixed freehub body dimensions and the 15mm inside diameter cannot be made
smaller due to fixed axle dimensions.

(In theory, it is possible to make a hub
that uses different bearing size between the hub shell and the axle than it
uses between the freehub body and the axle, but that's not much help with today's
ridiculously small chainrings typical of MTBs -- for example a 20 tooth chainring
has 40 millimeter radius as opposed to the 170 millimeter length typical of
cranks, multiplying the weight of the cyclist by a factor of 4.25x so in fact
the freehub body bearings are the most important bearings in a hub due to huge
chain loads.)

It is very important in a hub that bearing service is simple, because unlike in
a bottom bracket, changing the entire hub is not feasible because it takes many
hours to re-spoke the wheel for a new hub. In fact, changing a hub is probably
the second most difficult component in a bicycle to change (with the most
difficult being the frame) so it is of utmost importance that most hub bearings
service can happen without special tools. Cup and cone bearings allow
regreasing after water intrusion without expensive tools, and the balls and
cones can be changed without expensive tools. The rarest failure, cup failure,
requires a press fit tool but that's the only case where a cup and cone hub
requires non-standard tools.

Thus, hubs should ideally use cup-and-cone bearings. The only reason one cannot
find expensive ["boutique"](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html#boutique) hubs with cup-and-cone bearings is that nearly everyone
who can fool unsuspecting cyclists to buy a custom "boutique" hub at a great
price can set up a CNC machining shop to manufacture hub shells and then put in
industrial cartridge bearings bought from bearing manufacturers, but having
capacity to manufacture cup-and-cone bearings is only possible for major
players like Shimano.

Comment: To be fair: For cup&cone bearing hubs you usually need specific, narrow wrenches. For cartridge bearings a cheap bearing press is sufficient (I guess in a pinch you could even use a threaded rod, nuts and some washers). Getting the play/preload on a cup&cone bearing just right can be tricky.

Comment: This is the same FUD that you spread all over the site even where it os off-topic. "Only Shimano hubs are good." Even very high quality and quite expensive hubs like DT-Swiss use cartridge bearings and work just fine.

Comment: Some comments, with more possibly forthcoming as I digest this. 1) You appear to assert that square taper spindle failures were common. Is this true? My only recollection is that an early generation of titanium spindle Campy BBs had a number of failures - but essentially no ST spindles are made of ti. 2) On Octalink BBs, how does the left crank loosen? This is not a failure I've heard of. Also, on that line, you criticize the design as a non-press fit, whereas later on you characterize press fit frames as bad.

Comment: 3) You criticize 6902 bearings as too small for hubs. The thing is, a lot of reliable hubs use them. 6902 is a rear hub bearing, and recall that there are typically _multiple_ bearings in the hub itself _plus_ an extra in the freehub body. 4) It's true that cartridge bearing replacement requires specialized tools. a) You can outsource that to your bike shop, and b) recall that cups and cones will also wear eventually, and these are quite a bit harder to replace than the balls.

Comment: 5) Under headsets, you state that cartridge bearings are simpler to change than cup and cone. In hubs, you assert the reverse. This is a bit unclear. If you meant that you could remove and replace headset cups, that too requires specialized tools, no? This might be worthy of clarifying.

Comment: 6) There is absolutely no consensus that Hollowtech II is the "the only satisfactory bottom bracket". Good square taper systems are trouble free. Campy's Ultra-Torque system is also reportedly trouble free.

Comment: @WeiwenNg the square taper interface is indeed quite prone to failure. Tapered interfaces are cool in hard materials (glass bottles in chemistry labs, hardened steel in lathes) when made to high standards. In inexpensive mass production and aluminium it is bound to fail.

Comment: Shimano protected anything sensible in Hollowtech II with patents. It has been nearly impossible to make a similar reliable bottom bracket. Look at the rubbish design of SRAM GXP bottom brackets. They were not designed by brain dead idiots but rather by engineers who had to work with constraints that blocked good solutions.

Comment: @Weiwen Ng One of HT2’s benefits is that it can be removed and reinstalled in the field/on the road. All of those big fixing bolt-style cranks cannot, at least not easily and with standard multi tools. However, Shimano is moving towards that style anyways because of easier installation, so it’s a moot point.

Comment: A bearing press is hardly a sophisticated tool. Compare that to really nasty stuff like BSA threading or the umpteen number of specialty bike tools. Pressing bearings into parts is industry standard for practically any product but bikes. That it is often so sloppily and incompetently done in BB shells is another topic (Hambini addresses at length).